# pgAdmin 4, no built-in SSH tunnel config?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Just tried using pgAdmin 4 for the first time.
It looks like there's no built-in SSH tunnel config for connection.
I searched the docs but there's no mention of the feature.

Is it gone for good?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

SSH Tunneling is now available as of version 3.1 - https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/release_notes_3_1.html

---

**Original answer:**

Looks like they plan on having it for v2.0, which could be up to a year away, though they say that they are open to having it sooner.

> I hope we'll be able to add SSH support sooner rather
>   than later.

https://www.mail-archive.com/pgadmin-support@postgresql.org/msg15175.html

Comment: Now that v2.0 is out, how do we do it?

Comment: Looks like SSH support is still unavailable. You'd have to set up an ssh proxy and tunnel through that still.

Comment: For those looking to do this in Windows, I wrote an answer on how to [establish a connection through a PuTTY SSH Tunnel](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/199474/103411).