# pgAdmin 4: How to establish a connection through an SSH tunnel/interface in Windows

Tags: postgresql, windows, pgadmin-4, ssh, interface

I installed the latest pgAdmin 4 (v2.1) but I found out that ([related thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151465/pgadmin-4-no-built-in-ssh-tunnel-config)), for the moment, the only way to establish a connection through an SSH tunneling is using another outside process, an [example in the pgAdmin's forum](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BOCxowknMu3whL9mVJSJgKw6JExpuKO8b3u%3Drn33i-P%2BOkMCg%40mail.gmail.com) says:

> I setup a tunnel as follows:
>
> ```
> ssh -f dpage(at)hostname(dot)enterprisedb(dot)com -L 5999: hostname.enterprisedb.com:5432 -N
> ```
>
> (...) I was running on Mac, but the same procedure should work on Linux. On
> Windows, there's a tunnelling app in Putty iirc, but I don't know how
> to use it offhand.

I have found a simple [PuTTY tutorial to establish a connection using an SSH Tunnel](http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html).

The connection is established but it seems, when I try to connect through pgAdmin it fails or is refused (using *127.0.0.1:3306* or *127.0.0.1:5432* as the tunnel's destination). Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So in this step of that [PuTTY SSH tunnel tutorial](http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html):

[image: Add tunnel in PuTTY]

I used instead **5432** as the *Source port* and **my.tunnel.domain:5432** as the *Destination*.

Then in the connection details:

[image: PuTTY connection details]

In the *Host Name* I placed the server to connect to (the one with the DB: **my.db.domain**), but the login credentials relate to the tunnel's **my.tunnel.domain** (e.g. *Connection > Data* has the tunnel's domain user and *Connection > SSH > Auth* has the tunnel's domain private key).

I *opened* this connection (it opens up a window with a terminal, if successful) and finally in the pgAdmin 4 (v2.1) *Create Server...* window, I just added **localhost** as the *Host name/address* and **5432** as the *Port*, with the credentials relating to the **my.db.domain**:

[image: pgAdmin SSH Tunnel localhost connection]

The DB connection is established and works normally if the PuTTY window with the terminal is active.

Another and more verbose tutorial on how to set a Putty SSH tunnel can be found [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/38-PuTTY-for-SSH-Tunneling-to-PostgreSQL-Server.html).

Answer (score 6):

In newer version of PGAdmin4 you can configure SSH-tunnel (there is a tab for this there, but you need to use key in PEM format, not in RFC4716 that is now generated by default with `ssh-keygen`.

Use

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096
```

More information [here](https://t0ha.ru/en/faq/software/2019/06/05/faq-how-to-connect-pgadmin4-to-db-through-ssh-tunnel-with-public-key-authentication.html?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=answer)

Comment: I'm accessing my AWS RDS database via a tunnel through an EC2 instance and this is what got pgAdmin working for me. Set the PEM file in SSH Tunnel > Identity file and it will work.
Details on how to convert the PPK file to PEM here.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/convert-pem-file-into-ppk/

Comment: this solved the problem for me as well but, for some reason ssh configurations wont save and now it prompts for a password for the PEM file which is odd. If only mysql workbench had a postgres version.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add one tip to CPHPython's excellent answer because I've just wasted several days trying to find my mistake. My postgresql server running on my remote server runs on the standard port 5432 and my local postgresql server running on my Windows 10 laptop also uses port 5432. So, I needed to assign a free local port to this tunnel. I chose 8002. Here is my mistake when configuring the tunnel:
I entered 8002 for the Source port (correct),
but I entered localhost:8002 for the Destination (WRONG!)

The following screenshot shows the correct settings. The Source port is the port you want to use on your local machine, but the Destination needs to use the port assigned to Postgresql on the remote server (it's obvious now with hindsight), the standard 5432.
[image: Different local and destination ports]